# Why bash version do not support time up to millisecond?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, time

Want to get the time in UNIX server up to millisecond but the output show below.
Currently using bash version 3.2.57(1)

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S.%N                         
2020-10-21:16:06:59.%N
```

Did bash version 3.2.57(1) do not support time to millisecond? How should I do to get time up to millisecond in this bash version?

Comment: bash version 3.2.57(1)? That sounds like macOS, not Ubuntu. Anyway, this has nothing to do with `bash`, but with whichever version of `date` you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This does smell like a Mac problem.

```bsh
$ uname -sr
Darwin 19.6.0

$ /bin/date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S.%N
2020-10-21:08:07:50.N

$ /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S.%N
2020-10-21:08:07:53.827515000
```

The latter `date` was installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)

Answer (score 0):

date is not an internal bash command

Which version is your date command?

$ /bin/date --version

Is there %N mentioned for nano seconds, if you look at the outcome of:

$ man date

?

Probably you'll have to port a newer version of date to your system or write a simple programm which doesn't anything than print a timestamp.